# shutil.copy() function got error message FileNotFoundError

Tags: python

I'm studying the python with the book automate the boring stuff with python. But I got some problem to execute basic code.

```
>>> import shutil, os
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path.home()
>>> shutil.copy(p / 'spam.txt', p / 'some_folder')
```

This is the code I'm trying to run. But as I enter this code, I got error message "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\name\spam.txt'  ". But I tried making spam.txt and spam  folder. But it doesn't work. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I made both 'spam.txt', and 'some_folder' too. But I got the same error.

Comment: What does it print if you say: `print(list(p.iterdir()))`? Does `C:\Users\name\` exist?

Comment: I think it works correctly. It shows a list of paths

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried the code and it's working perfectly, you have to `right click` in your `home` folder -> `new` ->  `text document` and name it `spam`, then the `some_folfer` will be created with a copy of the content of `spam.txt`

Comment: I cleared this error, the problem was I didn't make a spam.txt at the home folder. I appreciate your answer.